# LINQ Contains clause - more then one value in criteria

Tags: linq

I have a collection which is filtered based on criteria for which I am using contains clause given below.
I am further creating a new collection based on filtered records and returning the same.

**Issue**:

If I have more then one value in "multipleCodes" which is used in contains clause.. it does not work.
If I put only 1 value... it does work.

Any idea what am I missing ? or is there any better approach to filter records and retrun only filtered resultset ?

```
collectionToFilter.Where(d => (d.Code.**Contains**(multipleCodes)) &&
                d.NeededDate > minNeedDate && d.NeededDate < maxNeedDate)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(d => filteredCollection.Add(d));
```

Comment: is the `Code` property a string?  and is the `multipleCodes` variable a collection of strings?

Comment: @RobertPetz - multipleCodes is variable having multiple values separated by comma. below response from James worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I wanted to show you a cleaner and more readable answer.

```
var _multipleCodes = multipleCodes.Split(',');
collectionToFilter.Where(d => _multipleCodes.Contains(d.Code));
```

Comment: @Amit I get the feeling you have a SQL background and wanted to replicate `WHERE d.Code IN (...values...)` - I do this all the time to on accident as well.  Just reversing the logic for Linq (as above) usually solves it in most cases.

Comment: yes I do have SQL background and during testing I found the first approach was not working 100% and I tried executing with your approach and I got the exactly the same count as I got in sql query.

Comment: thought so. if you think about the keywords being used - in SQL a single value is **IN** a collection of possibilities.  in Linq a collection of possibilities is being tested if it **CONTAINS** a single value.  so it's querying from the opposite direction essentially

Answer (score 2):

```
collectionToFilter.Where(d => (multipleCodes.Any(mc=>d.Code.Contains(mc))) &&
```

Comment: As a note - it wasn't clear from that question that `Code` was a string and not a collection.  This drastically changes the effectiveness of this answer.  If `Code` were a collection this work run fine, but since it is a string type `Contains` is a different method altogether that will test if the value of `mc` exists *inside* of that string rather than if that string *equals* `mc`.  Depending on the values, that could return that `BC` does exist in `ABCD` even though they are different codes.

Comment: Aha... It being a single comma-separated string never even occurred to me..